# JPA+HIBERNATE: cartesian product in Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, jpql, cartesian-product, java-persistence-api

I try to explain the problem. I have an entity with ManyToMany relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE1")
public class Table1 implements Serializable {

...

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Table1
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name="TABLE2"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_ELEMENTS1")
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_ELEMENTS2")
        }
    )
private List<Table1> elements;

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Table1
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="elements")
private List<Table1> elementOf;

...

}
```

Db table are:

```
TABLE1
ID      ...
55499   ...
55498   ...
55497   ...

TABLE2
ID_ELEMENTS1    ID_ELEMENTS2
55499           55498
55499           55497
```

When I try to execute following jpql query

```
SELECT  
    t  
FROM  
    Table1 t  
    LEFT JOIN FETCH t.elementOf 
WHERE  
    t.id = 55499
```

result is an arraylist with **two** elements (with id 55499) and every element has an arraylist of two elements (one with id 55498 and one with id 55497). The result I would like to obtain is **one** element (with id 55499) with arraylist of two elements (one with id 55498 and one with id 55497).
I hope I was clear. Can you help me to optimize the java object result (I vaguely remember QueryHints.BATCH in eclipselink)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified the `join` in the query, that's what gets executed. JPA provider will not remove duplicates automatically.

You can just add `distinct` in the query to remove any duplicates:

```
SELECT  
    DISTINCT t  
FROM  
    Table1 t  
    LEFT JOIN FETCH t.elementOf 
WHERE  
    t.id = 55499
```